# Distance and uniqueness for projections

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{W}$ be a subspace of the finite-dimensional inner product space $\mathbb{V}$, and let $\overrightarrow v \in V$. Show that $P_{W}(\overrightarrow v)$ is the unique closest vector in $\mathbb{W}$ to $\overrightarrow v$.

Uniqueness is easy to show by constructing any basis for $\mathbb{W}$, by definition any vector in $\mathbb{W}$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination of a basis. I'm having a hard time to show it is the closest vector:

$||\overrightarrow v-P_{W}(\overrightarrow v)||=Proj_{W^{\perp}}(\overrightarrow v)$

I then have to take an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{W}$ and show that $||\overrightarrow v-\overrightarrow w||$ ($\overrightarrow w \in \mathbb{W}$) is less or equal to $Proj_{W^{\perp}}(\overrightarrow v)$. Any hints on how to go about it?

Comment: What is your definition of projection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need:

**Claim**.- Let $\;w_0\in W\;$ , then for all $\;w\in W\;$ we have that

$$\;v-w_0\perp W\;\implies\;\left\|v-w_0\right\|\le\left\|v-w\right\| $$

**Proof**: For any $\;w\in W\;$ we have

$$\left\|v-w\right\|^2=\left\|v-w_0+w_0-w\right\|^2=\left\|v-w_0\right\|^2+\left\|w_0-w\right\|^2\ge\left\|v-w_0\right\|^2$$

since $\;w_0-w\in W\;$ and we've finished.

Choose now an orthonormal basis $\;\{w_1,...,w_k\}\;$ of $\;W\;$, so for any $\;1\le j\le k\;$ :

$$\left\langle\,v-P_W(v),w_j\,\right\rangle=\langle v,w_j\rangle-\langle P_W(v),w_j\rangle=\langle v,w_j\rangle-\sum_{i=1}^k\langle v,w_i\rangle\langle w_i,w_j\rangle=$$

$$=\langle v,w_j\rangle-\langle v,w_j\rangle=0$$

so $\;v-P_W(v)\perp W\;$ .